# Select with date from newer row

Tags: sql, sybase-asa

I have a table that looks like this:

```
containerID StartDate,  EndDate
10          2018-09-01  2019-10-01  
5           2018-08-12  2019-08-01
1           2018-08-02  2019-09-01
```

What I want is a select statement that return these rows but the end date should be the start date of the next row if there is a row above otherwise the same rows end date

So the result should be like this:

```
containerID StartDate,  EndDate
10          2018-09-01  2019-10-01  
5           2018-08-12  2018-09-01
1           2018-08-02  2018-08-12
```

It should also work if there is only one row and if there are no rows above when sorted descending on containerID

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?

Comment: Next row - according to what?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sybase anywhere

Comment: next row according to containerID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `lead()`:

```
select containerId, startDate,
       lead(startDate, 1, endDate) over (partition by containerId order by startDate) as EndDate
from t;
```

Comment: this query always puts out the endnote in the lead statement